# image background on page

Tags: image, background

I have an image a, which has it's own background (white). I want to put the image a on a page that has another big image b on it. I wonder if there is a way to make the background of image a to be the image b. can I achieve that with css? or I have to change the properties of the image a in order to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You say image A has a "white background", but from a computer's standpoint, it has **no** background. If you want to lay an image over another and have the second image show through in places, you'll need the top image to have true transparency.

Comment: what does it mean to be true transparency? put it in image editor and change it's transparency?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change those white pixels to actual transparent ones.